# Unable to map values to a different key in Django Rest Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to serialize input data to different keys using Django Rest Framework serializer like this

```
class BooHoo(serializers.Serializer):
    boo = serializers.CharField(source="hoo")


boohoo_serializer = BooHoo(data={"hoo": 1234})
```

I am expecting the `validated_data` to be, in this case

```
{"boo": 1234}
```

But when I call `is_valid()` it throws error that `boo` is required field and when I provide `default=None` in serializer I always get `None` in the result. Somewhere it's not mapping the value to the `source` key.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `required` keyword argument to `CharField` constructor

```
boo = serializers.CharField(source="hoo", required=False)
```

Comment: In this case it returns empty dict

Comment: If you just wanted to serialize the data pass it directly like `BooHoo({"hoo": "1234"})` , Also no need to call `is_valid()` in that case and you will get data in `boohoo_serializer.data`

Comment: That's what I did right now. But in future I wanted to add some validations in serializer.